# Java main-class in python-syntax

Tags: java, python, comparison, class-design

this is an example Java Class with a main method.

```
public class MyMainClass{
    public static void main(){
        doThings();
    }
}
```

To start it i have to do a "javac" on it and then a "java" on its output.

I've been experimenting quite a bit with python lately, but i couldn't figure out how to structure my py-document to function exactly like a Java Class with main function. For example i tried to code Python like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def method(self):
        print("in main")

def main():
    mc = MyClass()
    mc.method()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But it doens't work. The output i get when starting the interpreter is:

```
   C:\Users\altug>python MyClass.py
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "MyClass.py", line 9, in <module>
   main()
   NameError: name 'main' is not defined
```

Something is wrong with its indentation or i admit even logical errors on my behalf. Can someone help me to code a Python-main-class that looks exactly like a Java class?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work - what error are you getting?

Comment: The code you posted *does* work. Is the file you're running exactly the same?

Comment: the problem was that after pasting the code into the websites code block field the "def main():" lost its indentation and was on the same level as the if clause, making it work. But alas the closest to Java is Mike Thomsons post. Its even closer than code with "def main():" because its really "like putting funcionality" just into main and the class just like in java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not...

```
class MyClass:
    def method(self):
        print("in main")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyClass().method()
```

That's the closest thing to Java that you'll get here.

Answer (score 2):

It seems OK to me:

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class MyClass:
...     def method(self):
...         print("in main")
... 
>>> def main():
...     mc = MyClass()
...     mc.method()
... 
>>> if __name__ == "__main__":
...     main()
... 
in main
```

What is the problem that you are experiencing?

Or, are you looking for something like the following?

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class MyClass:
...     @staticmethod
...     def main():
...         print("in main")
... 
>>> if __name__ == "__main__":
...     MyClass.main()
... 
in main
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python equivalent of your Java Class with a main method would be:

```
class MyClass:
    def main(self):
        print("in main")
        doThings()
```

You create an instance and call its method:

```
mc = MyClass()
mc.main()
```

I think the confusion is that you are using a main() function for your program, which isn't necessary, but is good practice. But your code seems fine.